# Joining two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.3

I have the following tables is postgres (postgis). Both the tables have 1st,2nd,3rd column of type character varying(9000) and 4th column of type "geometry" (POINT geometry containing (latitude,longitude)):

```
Table1
Column1      Column2             Column3    the_geom
Oklahoma     numericalValue1     719        NULL
Oklahoma     geometry            NULL       (34.6,95.3)
Oklahoma     liesIn              America    NULL

Table2
Column1        Column2            Column3     the_geom
Mississippi    liesIn             America     NULL
Mississippi    geometry           NULL        (32.7,-89.53)
Mississippi    numericalValue2    15.3        NULL
```

I want to run the following query performing a spatial join on Table 1 and Table2. Table1 and Table2 shown in the question are toy tables, in my actual dataset they contain a million rows each. When I run the query given below, I find that my query takes an exceptionally long time (more than 10 hours) to run. Can someone please suggest if there is some way by which I may optimize the query by reformulating the query.

```
select * from Table1 s1, Table1 s2, Table1 s3, Table2 s4, Table2 s5, Table2 s6 where
s1.column2='numericalValue1' and     
s2.column2='geometry' and 
s3.column2='liesIn' and 
s1.column1=s2.column1 and 
s2.column1=s3.column1 and 
s4.column2='liesIn' and 
s5.column2='geometry' and 
s6.column2='numericalValue2' and 
s4.column1=s5.column1 and 
s5.column1=s6.column1 and 
ST_DWithin(s2.the_geom, s5.the_geom, 5) 
order by (cast(s1.column3 as double precision)+cast(s6.column3 as double precision)) 
limit 1;
```

Comment: This is a horrible database design. No wonder that you are facing performance issues. A database is about entities related to each other, e.g. states and countries, each with their own attributes. So you'd have a country table and a state table and each state record would refer to a country, have a location and so on. You, however, have a "thing" consisting of three "things", the combination of which forms an attribute of a virtual record, plus its location where appropriate. And you even have it twice. Change your datamodel and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Swap the axis order so that your geometries are (X Y) or (long lat)
2. If you don't have a GiST spatial index, then investigate on how to add one
3. I'm assuming you are using SRID=4326 or [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326), which has units of degrees. So a distance of 50000000 is illogical and massive, and will do a cross-join an take a long time to do. Either try a smaller distance, like 0.01 degrees, or investigate using a `geography` type to use linear distances, or other tricks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Metric used by  ST_DWithin for distance is meters. Correct? Please correct me if I am wrong. Also I used Gist index, swapped axis order, made distance=50000 (corresponding to 50 km). Still postgres is taking a lot of time

Comment: @JannatArora you might want to investigate the `geography` type if you want to use metric distances for ST_DWithin. This is often a tricky detail to figure out, as there isn't one solution for everyone (e.g. change the database type, change the SRID, make a geography index cast, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to change data type from geometric to geography, if yes how?

Comment: cast it with `geom::geography` , or change the data type in the table

Comment: Ok. How do I change the data type in the table. I am a bit novice at this, can you please help me with this a bit?

Comment: Also postgis docs mention: "Standard geometry type data will autocast to geography if it is of SRID 4326" And I used the following function: ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' ||
longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')',4326); for assigning values to geometry data type.

Comment: use something like `ALTER my_table ALTER COLUMN geo TYPE geography USING geo::geography;`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @MikeT's answer, first of all ensure you have an index on `subject` and another for `column2`/`predicate` for both tables.

I'd say that 1 million rows is not that much, even a sequential scan will go through it in just a few seconds. If a query takes longer than 1-2 minutes (let alone 10 hours!) there's good reason to believe something in the query is off (like in this case, as Mike states, a virtual cross-join between s2 and s5, producing a billion tuples), or the query requires missing indexes.

I find very useful using joins (as opposed to having all the joining conditions in the where clause) to make debugging queries much easier. For example, the query below is exactly the same as yours, but you can easily comment out joins on s1, s3, s4 and s6 to try and isolate and pinpoint the problem.

```
select *
from Table1 s2
join Table2 s5 on (ST_DWithin(s2.the_geom, s5.the_geom, 50000000))
join Table1 s1 on (s1.subject=s2.subject and s1.column2='numericalValue1')
join Table1 s3 on (s2.subject=s3.subject and s3.column2='liesIn')
join Table2 s4 on (s4.subject=s5.subject and s4.column2='liesIn')
join Table2 s6 on (s5.subject=s6.subject and s6.predicate='numericalValue2')
where s2.column2='geometry' and s5.column2='geometry'
order by (cast(s1.column3 as double precision)+cast(s6.column3 as double precision)) 
limit 1
```